# I have a header.jsp whose style keeps changing for different logins its a dynamic header

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dynamic

For example if admin logs in i need 2 tabs in header , and if  a user logs in i need 1 tab. How to proceed with this?
I have included  and i want to know the javascript for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a java Script for this. you have to get a Database connectivity. Create a Table in a DB that have Admin name and user's name. when Login, if it's admin it will prompt to the page that will have 2 headers if not it will re-direct to the page that will have one header. You can achieve this by using `response.sendRedirect()` function. in your JSP page

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have to provide logged user type like admin or user at login time . if logged user type is admin then pass url parameter like `userType='ADMIN' or userType='USER'`  and check in header.jsp page if `userType='ADMIN'` load 2 tabs otherwise one tab.